# How to set correct logstash/elasticsearch/kibana configuration?

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using filebeat, logstash, elasticsearch and kibana to show my logs. Client and servers run on Ubuntu 16.04. 
When I try to replace `@timestamp` with logtime all new logs disappear.

Log example:

```
2018-02-07 18:08:15.717 DEBUG 2341 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] company.controller.MyController     : some log message : hello
```

input config file `02-beats-input.conf`:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
```

filter config file: `10-java-filter.conf`

```
filter {
  if [type] == "java" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} %{LOGLEVEL:level} \[%{DATA:thread}\] %{JAVACLASS:class} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      overwrite => [ "message" ]
      remove_field => [ "host", "count", "fields", "@version", "input_type", "offset", "source", "tags", "type" ]
  }

  date {
    match => [ "logtime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
    target => "@timestamp"
    locale => "en"
    timezone => "UTC"
  }
}
```

30-elasticsearch-output.conf:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

but when I remove date filter - everything works good. how can I replase @timestamp in correct way to display all logs.
Thank you.

Comment: Are there any error logs in logstash log file? Is logstash still running and just not sending data, or does it fail altogether? (some plugins shut logstash down instead of handling exceptions)

Comment: A possible problem when replacing the timestamp is that the log timestamp might fall outside of the range used in kibana: for example, if you are parsing logs from yesterday and the kibana date range is only for today, you won't see anything in Kibana.